# Count repetitive values in column B based on unique value in column A

Tags: excel

I have the following table:

```
1 John Doe
  John Doe
2 Adam Smith
  Adam Smith
  Adam Smith
```

I need to count the number of times a name appears for each number value in column A. The numbers are unique.

Comment: What have you tried? `COUNTIFS()`?

Comment: @BruceWayne how would I do that? I can't count the number of names associated with "1" or with "2" because the answer will always be 1 name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place this formula in cell C1 and drag down until the end.

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(A1),COUNTIF(B:B,B1),"")
```

[image]

*n.b. - you can more clearly define row numbers instead of using `B:B` if you like as well*